# List properties using SharePoint.Client

Tags: list

How can I get a list of property/value pairs of a List? I have the following code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://lalala.com");
Web web = context.Web;
Guid g = new Guid("lalala");
List list = web.Lists.GetById(g);
foreach (var prop in list.Properties) {
  Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " " + prop.Value);
}
```

List properties: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFvpO.jpg

Answer (score 1):

first you need to explain what is your code doing? im confused ;)

```
foreach (var prop in what) {
  // Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " " + prop.Value);
}
```

where did what come from? secondly what do you mean by properties? `prop.Name + " " + prop.Value` to me that means you want to get the values of a list item not the list properties?

to get the list value:

```
   //list name 
   string listname = list.Title;
```

do the same for other values!

for the actual list properties (settings)

```
  SPField field = ((SPList)list).Fields.GetField("Author"); 
object fieldValue = field.GetFieldValue(((SPListItem)item)[field.Title].ToString());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647806/accessing-splistitem-properties-in-sharepoint

Comment: I'd like to iterate over, or get properties by name, of the List instance. Not the properties of the List item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of getting the wanted list correctly from a specified web, and then writing the list properties out in the console screen:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(@"http://UrlGoesHere");
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb; //If you have your list in the root level
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListNameGoesHere");
var prop = list.PropertiesXml;
Console.WriteLine(prop);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The output is an XML formatted text.